# Only run function it is not already running

Tags: python, mouse

I need to make on auto clicker that, when the mouse is clicked once (using the 'mouse' module), presses another 5 times. However, I also need to make sure that only the clicks done by the user activate it. Currently (because I don't need an unstoppable mouse as I've already had), it only prints "clicking". This is what I have so far.

```
jack = 0
import keyboard
import mouse
import sys
from time import sleep
def spamClick(f, jeff):
    if jeff <= 0:
        jeff = jeff+1
        for i in range(f):
            #mouse.click()
            print ("Clicking")
            sleep(0.1)
        jeff = 0
mouse.on_click(spamClick, args=(5, jack))
#keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+g', spamClick)
keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+#', mouse.unhook_all)
keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+#', sys.exit)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Set and check a flag.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 that's what the if Jeff <= 0 part should do...

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix for this is having a top level variable keeping track of the state.
The issue is that you have a function that does an action that starts itself again.

It's functionally the same as

```
def examplecode():
    print("Do stuff")
    examplecode()
```

This is the same as an infinite loop, in your case even worse because you call the function multiple times every time (5 times per action).

So your options to prevent that are as follows:

- Have two different ways of clicks, one that triggers the "onclick" event, and one that doesn't.
- Use a helper function that keeps track of the "state" of your program. Instead of calling "spamClick()" as your onclick event add the following to your program:

A top level variable that is True when you want it to accept clicks: `isUser=True`

A function you call instead of "spamclick" that checks the state of the global Var and only then triggers the code:

```
def examplefunc(num,var):
    if isUser:
        isUser=False
        spamClick(num,var)
        isUser=True
```

I still don't get how your program just "clicks endlessly" instead of crashing due to hitting max recursion depth, but this should work (while being very hacky)

Edit: You should use better naming for variables instead of "jeff", it will make your life worse if you don't down the line. For example "isUser" indicates that it's a boolean (because "isWhatever" indicates it holds a state as a boolean) and states if the input is by a user. Alternatively you could use `isFunctionRunning=False` that states if the function is on. You would have to switch all the True and False assignments in my example of course to still make sense.

Comment: I tried making Jeff global, having it Boolean, and several other things. I don't see how it still can run twice /stack up.

Comment: so using my examplefunc() and adding a `isUser=True` in the first line (and changing the onclick to `mouse.on_click(examplefunc, args=(5, jack))` still triggers the code multiple times?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes.